# Support of batch mode in tcpkill

Tags: tcp

I fire tcpkill with destination ip. Example

```
 tcpkill host 10.0.2.184
```

The problem I am facing is that, tcpkill doesn't come out after killing all tcp connection. After killing all tcp connection it waits infinitely and print following information:

```
tcpkill: listening on eth0 [host 10.0.2.184]
```

is there any batch mode or any patch , using which I can ask tcpkill to quit after closing all tcp connections.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution, inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14696427/how-can-bash-script-do-the-equivalent-of-ctrl-c-to-a-background-task) Stack Overflow question, that works by wrapping the command in another script:

```
#!/bin/bash

tcpkill host 10.0.2.184 &
sleep 7
for child in $(jobs -p); do
    echo kill "$child" && kill "$child"
done
wait $(jobs -p)
```